# Block heater cord hack

Tags: electrical, winter, block-heater, sealant

The end of my block heater cord that connects to the block heater is worn out. The rubber is dry and cracked. Because of this, it does not stay plugged in correctly.

To save some money I want to try to salvage this cord, since replacement cords are ridiculously expensive!

The only problem is that is does not stay snuggly plugged in, and seems like a nice tight single wrap of duct tape would do the trick.

I am concerned though that the duct tape might not survive the heat of that area. There is no exhaust close by, but it is a block heater, and it is plugged into the engine block.

Is there another material that might be even more durable for the job?

Comment: Do you have any images of the cord and where it plugs into?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: Is the issue where the cord plugs into the block heater or where you plug the cord into the outlet/extension cord?

Comment: The end that connects to block heater (see first sentence).

Comment: Is there a plug on the block heater end or just a molded rubber connection?

Comment: molded rubber connection.